# SQL Join on dates which have weak relation

Tags: mysql, sql, date, join, timestamp

Given the DB Schema below, i would like to join time_data with weather:

each city has some stations and each minute I save some data about the station in a time_data row.

The main problem is that I have weather information about every 2 hours so the join is a little bit harder for me.

Given a single time_data I would like to find the weather row which has the nearest (in timestamp) infos about the weather
(i.e. select, from all the weather rows which have a timestamp lower than the one of the single time_data, the one that has the maximum timestamp)

So finally I would like to obtain these data for each time_data row:

id, bikes, free, timestamp, version, station, wind_chill, wind_direction, wind_speed

It should be something like this but I don't know how to really achieve it:

```
SELECT time_data.*, weather.*
FROM time_data
JOIN weather ON weather.timestamp = 
(SELECT max(weather.timestamp)
 FROM weather
 WHERE weather.timestamp<time_data.timestamp) <-- the time_data should be the same of the time_data row considered in the join
WHERE time_data.station=23
ORDER BY time_data.timestamp;
```

Thanks in advance!

[image: Schema]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know MySQL, but I know it has a function to calculate the interval between two dates.. Using that function, try this:

```
 Select case when IntervalFunc(wo.timestamp, td.timestamp) <
                  IntervalFunc(td.timestamp, w1.timestamp) 
             then w0.wind_Direction else w1.Wind_Direction end WIndDirection,
        case when IntervalFunc(wo.timestamp, td.timestamp) <
                  IntervalFunc(td.timestamp, w1.timestamp) 
             then w0.wind_Speed else w1.Wind_Speed end WIndSpeed,
    -- etc.
 from time_date td
    left join Weather w0 
       on w0.timestamp = (Select Max(timestamp)
                          From weather 
                          where timestamp < td.timestamp )
    left join weather w1
       on w0.timestamp = (Select Min(timestamp)
                          From weather 
                          where timestamp > td.timestamp
 Where td.Id = @someID )
```

or, for all fields ...

```
Select * from Weather 
Where TimeStamp = 
    (Select case when IntervalFunc(wo.timestamp, td.timestamp) <
                  IntervalFunc(td.timestamp, w1.timestamp) 
             then w0.Timestamp else w1.Timestamp end 
     From time_date td
        left join Weather w0 
           on w0.timestamp = (Select Max(timestamp)
                              From weather 
                              where timestamp < td.timestamp )
        left join weather w1
           on w0.timestamp = (Select Min(timestamp)
                              From weather 
                              where timestamp > td.timestamp )
     Where td.Id = @someID )
```